# Python Kivy android app invalid signature error after optimising

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I created a simple android app with kivy/kivymd. Using buildozer running on Ubuntu in virtual box to generate the APK file. I have created an APK in debug mode and an APK release/signed mode, and also an APK optimised mode.

I tried uploading the debug mode, but google play store obviously doesn't accept the debug mode and it needs to be a release/signed mode.
By the way, the requirement right now is API level 29 at least.

I tried uploading the release/signed mode, but google play store need it to be optimised.

So, I optimised the release/signed copy APK and uploaded it, but this is where I am stuck.
The APK signature has become invalid. The exact ERROR is - (You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped?)
The optimised copy seems to have messed up the signature on the APK?

I have not found any Kivy documentation on this problem and it's been 2 days now trying to exhaust every single possibility, but with no joy.
Any input will be very much appreciated.